# How to display vector layer on google earth?

Tags: javascript, vector, google-earth

I am trying to find an effective way to display vector data on google earth.Is it possible to display vector data on top of google earth?If anyone has an idea to achieve this.Please share with us.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just need to convert your data into KML.  If you aren't sure how to do this, please provide some details on the format of your data, etc.

Comment: ok thanks for your quick reply.I know how to use kml on google map.But I just trying for a solution that can we do this by some layer configuraion on google earth.

Comment: You still need to make your question more clear.  KML is the language that powers Google Earth.  Google Maps happens to read in a subset of it.  KML is the appropriate answer to your current question as I understand it, so please make more clear exactly what you are trying to do, perhaps with examples, if you want a better answer.